# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "volume" Error

Tags: java, type-conversion, command-line-arguments, numberformatexception

I am working on a calculator which will calculate the volume or surface area of a sphere depending on what the input arguments are.

When I input "sphere volume 5" it throws a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "volume" Error. Can someone help point out what is causing this error?

Thanks

```
public class SimpleCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String operator = args[0];
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        double result;

        switch (operator) {
            case "+" :
                result = num1 + num2;
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
            
            case "-" :
                result = num1 - num2;
                System.out.println(result);
                break;

            case "*" :
                result = num1 * num2;
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
            
            case "/" :
                double dnum1 = num1;
                result = dnum1 / num2;
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
            
            case "sphere" :
            
            if (args[1] == "volume") {
                result = (4.0/3)* Math.PI * Math.pow(num2, 3);
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
            } else if (args[1] == "surface"){
                result = 4.0 * Math.PI * Math.pow(num2, 2);
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
            }
            break;
        }
        
    }

}
```

I initially had a String variable calcType to differentiate between "volume" and "surface" but I assumed doing that would be redundant as the args are Strings to begin with. This was my initial code:

```
            case "sphere" :
            String calcType = args[1];
            if (calcType.equals("volume")) {
                result = (4.0/3)* Math.PI * Math.pow(num2, 3);
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
            } else if (calcType.equals("surface")){
                result = 4.0 * Math.PI * Math.pow(num2, 2);
                System.out.println(result);
                break;
            }
            break;
```

Comment: You are providing three command line arguments. The second is `volume`. The expression `args[1]` refers to the second command line argument, and you try to convert it to an integer in `int num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[1])`.

Comment: But if I assign the integer value of args[1] to num1, shouldn't the actual value of args[1] still be a string? (thanks for the reply btw!)

Comment: The string "volume"  -- which is the value of `args[1]` -- has no "integer value".

Comment: What do you expect `Integer.parseInt("volume")` to return?

Answer (score 0):

If your inputs are "sphere" "volume" and "5" then since the first index of an array is 0 your args array will be like:

```
args[0] = "sphere";
args[1] = "volume";
args[2] = "5";
```

The problem is that when you parse args[1] into an integer you are trying to turn the string "volume" into a number when "volume" is not a number. As the exception you are getting is telling you.